# What is a good way to take fractional powers of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working on a problem that involves taking fractional powers of particular matrices.

For the matrix A with 2 on the main diagonal and -1 on the sub and super diagonal (the finite difference matrix for the Dirichlet Laplacian in 1D), there was basically no difference between using MATLAB's `sqrtm(A)` function and diagonalizing the matrix (`[V,D]=eig(A)`, `A = V\D*V`) and computing `V\D^(1/2)*V` even if the matrix was as large as 1000x1000. This made me think I could compute other fractional powers `V\D^(1/n)*V` that MATLAB does not have built in functions for.

However when I consider the matrix A for the Dirichlet Laplacian in 2D, there is a significant difference between MATLAB's sqrtm function and the diagonalization procedure I used above even if the matrix was as small as 100x100. In particular, MATLAB's sqrtm function is better and my results don't make any sense if I do it the other way.

I am wondering if anyone can explain why this happens and if there is a way to fix it so that I can compute fractional powers of a large matrix in MATLAB.

Comment: You can directly use something like `A^(2/3)`. Is there a reason this is undesirable?

Comment: It is not undesirable, I just didn't know it could be this easy! Someone has also informed me that expm(1/n*logm(A)) works too. Both of these are giving me matrices whose nth power differs from A by basically machine precision. Thanks again, if you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB has the ability to compute fractional powers of matrices by using the normal `^` operator which calls the `mpower` function when either of the arguments is a matrix. You can read a discussion of when fractional powers of matrices can be computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615614/non-integral-powers-of-a-matrix).

Your original issues may stem from the fact that you have mixed up the formula to compute matrices raised to a fractional power. The matrix should be diagonalized as $A = PDP^{-1}$. Then $A^\alpha = PD^\alpha P^{-1}$.

In MATLAB this can be done as follows (your code is a bit off):

```
[V,D]=eig(A);
Aalph = V*(D.^alph)/V;
```

Based on a quick test, it seems that this is exactly the method used by MATLAB inside  `mpower`. The following code returns exactly 0 (no differences due to finite precision) on my machine.

```
A = rand(1000);
alph = 2/3;
[V,D]=eig(A);
Aalph = V*(D.^alph)/V;
B = A^(alph);
max(abs(Aalph(:)-B(:)))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what happens when you think you remember a formula and don't stop to check that it is correct. At least now I won't be forgetting V*D/V any time soon. Thanks again for clearing that up.